# Can any differential equations be solved using the definition of the derivative?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Are there differential equations which can be solved using the definition of the derivative? I mean of course
\begin{align}
y(x)'=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{y(x+h)-y(x)}{h}.
\end{align}
I can't imagine it would be useful for ODE's of order two or more, but perhaps for first order ODE's it would be possible to evaluate the functional equation with a limit problem instead? For example, could the trivial ODE
\begin{align}
y(x)'=y(x)\quad\longrightarrow\quad y(x)=ce^x,
\end{align}
be solved using the definition of a derivative?

Using the definition of a derivative it would be
\begin{align}
\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{y(x+h)-y(x)}{h}-y(x)\right)=0.
\end{align}
For a given function $y(x)$ I can cook up some methods from early calculus classes on how to evaluate this, but I am at a loss for arbitrary functions. Is there anyway to suss out the answer of such a functional equation with limits?

Comment: That particular one is doable, actually: $y(x+h)=(1+h)y(x)+\dots$ where the $\dots$ is an error term. Replacing $h$ with $h/n$ and iterating $n$ times you get $y(x+h)=(1+h/n)^n y(x)+\dots$. If you can show that as $n \to \infty$ the $\dots$ goes to zero for any fixed $h$ then you're done. Unfortunately this last step is generally a quite nontrivial matter; in fact analytical steps like this one are important in the theory of numerical methods for differential equations.

Comment: If I understand your idea correctly, this is the explicit or forward Euler method. The numerical solution converges for Lipschitz continuous right sides using a straightforward calculation. This also works for larger first-order systems, which is the normal form for any ODE system. For better results see the higher-order Runge-Kutta methods (among others).

Comment: @LutzLehmann I was thinking about extracting an analytical solution as apposed to a numerical solution.

Comment: @Eli taking the limit of the numerical solution?

Comment: @ErdelvonMises I don't follow.

Comment: Really the only thing you can do with the limit definition "directly" is to write down a numerical method like what I did. You can then try to analytically "solve" this numerical method, which is what I described. The hard parts in general are controlling that error term (doable, with enough regularity in the equation) and taking the limit (usually not doable, but doable in this particular example).